# If Arabs were no nation, how did Arabic become the language of the Quran?

Tags: history, arabic

From history I came to know that before Islam the Arabs wer not considered a nation but any types of nomads people were called Arabs. How come Arabic is called a language in the Quran when the Arabs were not a nation?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Isla. What is the source of your claim that Arabs were no nation and what does it really refer to? For further information about our site and model please consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Answer (score 3):

*Before Islam the Arabs were not considered a nation*

This is not true. The Arabs were considered a coherent tribe (the word nation is a recent notion established in the 19th century CE). They are already mentioned in the Torah as a tribe of Ismail, Son of Abraham. True is that there hasn't been an established and centralised state in Arabia before Muhammad (p.b.u.h).

*Any types of nomads people were called Arabs*

The Arabs were all nomads, owing to the scarcity of the land. But only the nomads in Arabia, speaking Arabic, were called Arabs.

*How come Arabic is called a language in the Quran when the Arabs were not a nation?*

The Arabic language existed. The existence of a language is no way bound to the existence of a state. Now as before, there are by far more languages in this world than states. A language exists if it is spoken. The Arabs were not an important people before Muhammad (p.b.u.h). Neither the Torah nor the Gospel had been translated into Arabic at that time, but only into Aramaic, which is a related language but it cannot be understood directly by an Arab without any further study. The Quran is not revealed just for the Arabs but the Quran was indeed the first prophetic scripture available to them in their own language.